# Overriding an external style sheet without access to <Head>

Tags: css

I have a Ecommerce Host that does not allow access to the Header Tag or the External .CSS file.
I have to override using inline styles.
Problem is, I have to override Pseudo Class :active

Is there way to link an external style sheet from within an inline style so that I can style the pseudo classes?

Any simple alternatives? Without  access?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="blah-blah.css">` tag into head to make it work, but it's a bad practice, because it works slower and looks a bit bad, but I understand your situation :) Just put `<link>` at the end of the `<body>` and it'll work fine! For example:

File `styles.css`

```css
p {
    color: blue;
}
```

File `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Evil host holders didn't allow access this tag. Well, okay :D -->
</head>
<body>
  <p>I am blue, da ba dee da ba dai!</p>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</body>
</html>
```